# How to add new tree item/folder in fuelux tree

Tags: tree, fuelux

I'm using fuelux tree plugins, I need to add new item on the fly(not by reloading all tree data or refreshing a page), can any one give simple example how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no direct way to do this since all data for the tree comes from its `dataSource`.  This would be a good suggestion to post at https://fuelux.uservoice.com/